# Ошибка при сборке проекта после обновления Android Sudio

Tags: android, android-gradle

Обновил Gradle и саму студию на последнюю версию вылезли ошибки. Как их исправить?

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple
>   errors, see logs at
>   com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:558)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest.doFullTaskAction(ProcessApplicationManifest.java:208)
>   at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73) at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
>   at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267) at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
>   at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
>   at
>   org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Минифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="test.myapp">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:name=".db.AppDatabase"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="test.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/images_file_path" />
    </provider>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.hannesa2:FloatingActionButton:2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте глянуть здесь причину проблемы. Картинка в ответе [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474441/5330439)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, я уже решил проблему сделав миграцию проекта на библиотеку AndroidX